# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{x+\text{sgn}(x)}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help to integrate the following integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{x+\text{sgn}(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$
Where $$\text{sgn}(x):=\begin{cases}\dfrac{|x|}{x}&\text{if }x\neq0\\0&\text{if x=0}\end{cases}\;\Rightarrow\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0\\-1&\text{if }x<0\\0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$

But in this case of integrals I can't understand which value I will consider for $\text{sgn}(x)$. Because in the case of indefinite integrals no limits are given. Now since no limits are given therefore it is very difficult for me to understand which value of $\text{sgn}(x)$ to take. If I assume $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ then the above integral will be

$$\int \frac{1}{x+1}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x+1|+C$$

If I assume the value of $\text{sgn}(x)=-1$ then the above integral will be $$\int \frac{1}{x-1}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x-1|+C$$

And lastly if I assume $\text{sgn}(x)=0$, then the above integral will be $$\int \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x|+C$$

But how can be $3$ results possible for an indefinite integral? Here in this case, we can clearly see that there are $3$ different results occurring. Please help me out with this discrepancy. I am very much confused with this integral.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2Cx%2Bsgn%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: I would treat this as a piecewise function and integrate each piece.

Comment: The integral does not make sense when $x=0$ so consider two pieces when $x<0, x>0$. WA formula combines two cases into one expression.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed correctly that

if $x>0$ $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ then the above integral will be

$$\int \frac{1}{x+1}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x+1|+C$$

If $x<0$ $\text{sgn}(x)=-1$ then the above integral will be $$\int \frac{1}{x-1}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x-1|+C$$

$x=0$ is not in domain of the function
Now consider sum

$$\ln|x+1|+\ln|x-1|$$

When $x<0$ we want the first term of the sum to disappear, When $x>0$,We want second term of the sum to disappear

How can we do that? Notice

for $x<0$, $\text{sgn}(x)=-1$ which means $1+\text{sgn}(x)=0$

for $x<0$, $\text{sgn}(x)=-1$ which means $\frac{1-\text{sgn}(x)}{2}=1$

for $x>0$, $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ which means $1-\text{sgn}(x)=0$

for $x>0$, $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ which means $\frac{1+\text{sgn}(x)}{2}=1$

These equations are exactly suitable for disappearance of the intended parts of sum as per range of $x$

The final sum becomes

$$\frac{\left(1+\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)\ln|x+1|}{2}+\frac{\left(1-\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)\ln|x-1|}{2}$$

Which can be further rearranged as

$$\frac{\ln|x^2-1|}{2}+\left(\frac{\ln\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|}}{2}\right)\left(\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)$$

$$=\frac{\ln|x^2-1|}{2}+\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|}\right)^{\left(\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)}}{2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left[{|x^2-1|\cdot\left(\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|}\right)^{\left(\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)}}\right]$$
$$=\ln\left[\sqrt {\left[{|x^2-1|\cdot\left(\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|}\right)^{\left(\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)}}\right]}\right]$$

Finally
$$\int \frac{1}{x+\text{sgn}(x)}\mathrm{d}x=\ln\left[\sqrt {\left[{|x^2-1|\cdot\left(\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|}\right)^{\left(\text{sgn}\left(x\right)\right)}}\right]}\right]+C$$